# How to filter the inputs in Table with SWT.Virtual?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, swt, jface, tableviewer

In my project, I have a `TableViewer` which needs to show around 3000 items and also filter them. Without `SWT.VIRTUAL` the table takes multiple seconds to display. 
So, I implemented `ILazyContentProvider` and not using "ArrayContentProvider" but now I am facing issues in filtering the elements of `TableViewer`.

I am writing the below code for filtering but the `select` method is not running at all.

```
   private static class DefaultFilterextends ViewerFilter {
    
            private String searchText;
    
            public void setSearchText(final String searchText) {
                this.searchText = searchText;
            }
    
            @Override
            public boolean select(Viewer viewer, Object parentElement, Object element) {
                if (this.searchText == null) {
                    return true;
                }
                return (element.toString().contains(searchText) || element.toString().equals(searchText));
            }
    }
```

The below ContentProvider, I am writting

```
  private class LazyContentProvider implements ILazyContentProvider {

        private TableViewer viewer;
        private List<String> elements;

        public LazyContentProvider(TableViewer viewer) {
            this.viewer = viewer;
        }

        @Override
        public void dispose() {
        }

        @Override
        public void inputChanged(Viewer viewer, Object oldInput, Object newInput) {
            this.elements = (List<String>) newInput;
        }

        @Override
        public void updateElement(int index) {
            viewer.replace(elements.get(index), index);
        }

    }
```

Can someone please guide me how can I do the filteration of elements in TableViewer with SWT.VIRTUAL?

Comment: Could you guide me little more? How to do that in ContentProvider?
I am writting my own contentprovider which is implementing ILazyContentProvider.

Comment: I just want to search for a String, Could you guide me more how can I do that in this Content Provider which I added in my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TableViewer does not support filtering when `SWT.VIRTUAL` is used. Instead you must do the filtering in the content provider.

The content provider will need to maintain a filtered list of elements. For example:

```java
public class LazyContentProvider implements ILazyContentProvider
{
  private TableViewer viewer;
  private List<String> allElements;
  private List<String> filteredElements;


  public LazyContentProvider()
  {
    //
  }


  @Override
  public void dispose()
  {
    //
  }


  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  @Override
  public void inputChanged(final Viewer viewer, final Object oldInput, final Object newInput)
  {
    this.viewer = (TableViewer)viewer;

    allElements = (List<String>)newInput;

    filteredElements = allElements;
  }


  @Override
  public void updateElement(final int index)
  {
    viewer.replace(filteredElements.get(index), index);
  }


  public void filter(final String searchText)
  {
    filteredElements = allElements.stream().filter(element -> element.contains(searchText)).toList();

    viewer.setItemCount(filteredElements.size());

    viewer.refresh();
  }
}
```

Here I have added a `filteredElements` list that contains just the current filtered elements, this is used in `updateElement`.

I added a `filter` method which updates the filtered elements list. It also tells the table viewer about the new item count and refreshes the table.

The `.toList()` method in the filter stream requires Java 16, for older versions of Java use `.collect(Collectors.toList())`.